# setting security for listitem programatically

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, fast-for-sharepoint

how to set security for listitem programatically?
My Requirements as follows:
In list , while adding item to it.

I have two radio buttons.(i)view by every one (ii) view only by me...if i select 'view by every one' radiobutton, that items in the list should be able to view by everyone.if i select 'me only'.then that item ll viewed only by me .plz help me...is there any property to do this..thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Thre is no property to do this OOTB from simply adding an item into a SharePoint List.  If you are comfortable in creating / writing code then an event receiver for the ItemAdded event which takes the value of the metadata selected (View By Everyone / Only Me) then breaks the inheritance of the SPList (Parent List) and sets the permissions explicitly.  Should the "View by everyone" be selected then the handler will just ignore the permissions.  If you have not done code before let me know and i could try to give you a simple code example.

Comment: Ya sure i wann it:)

Comment: Nadeem Below had beaten me to this :) thanks Nadeem :) Some additions below:

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code as a starting point:

```
        item.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
        SPUser user = web.CurrentUser;
        SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(user);
        roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(web.RoleDefinitions["Full Control"]);
        item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
```

This will give the current user full control on the item.

Comment: how to set roledefinition for ly view..can u plz..

Answer (score 1):

Nadeem Below had beaten me to this :) thanks Nadeem :) Some additions below:

```
    public class YourClass: SPItemEventReceiver
     {
       public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
       {
          SPListItem item=properties.ListItem;
          item.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
          SPUser user = web.CurrentUser;
          SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(user);
          roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(web.RoleDefinitions["Full Control"]);
          item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);      
          item.Update(); 
         //must!!! or you `can use item.SystemUpdate() also based on your equirement
       }
     }
```

Comment: hi Chris Pettigrew...thanx for ur answer..i am newbie ...where should i have to add this code...In feature1.eventreceiver.cs???? i want more precisely....plz

Comment: Can you let me know if you are using 2010 or 2007 and what version of visual studio you are using so i can give you relevant instructions

Comment: SharePoint 2010 ,visual studio 2010

Comment: hi..i am using ItemAdding event receiver...i'm not able to get listitem by  this code.                  SPListItem item=properties.ListItem;                                       plz help me...